# ServerSocket do not work

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner. I run the following code.

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ServerSocket server = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Socket client = server.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

But i can only see app stopped working message in emulator when it is run. I found that the error occur on the statement Socket client = server.accept();. I think this statement will wait until a client request is accepted. these user permissions are also added.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I am using android studio. and sdk 14.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant run network on UI thread , and i think you need while(1) when accept , try this :

```html
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
  try {
        Socket client = server.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}).start();
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it works. but i don't know when this thread starts. i make a break point inside the thread. but program never stopped at there.

Answer (score 0):

Android UI Thread ever do not long operation.so you should start thread in your code.e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new thread(){
          void run(){
            server.accept();
          }    
    }.start();
 }
```